# Constant for lb://

Tags: java, spring-cloud

Does any class or interface in Spring provide a constant (public static final variable) for the load balanced scheme, that is the string "lb://"? I don't want to hard code it everywhere or create my own class/enum for it

```java
public static final String lbScheme = "lb://";
```

Comment: nope, you have to define it yourself.

Comment: Just define it for yourself. If you find a more convenient definition at a later date, use your IDE to replace usages of your current symbol with the alternative.

Comment: I'll 2nd the no from the spring cloud team. If we had a constant it would just be "lb" since we use a class to separate the URI into parts and we only get the scheme.